# How do separate columns depending on time in R?

Tags: r, multiple-columns

we are research students and are a bit struggling with R.

First we tried to add morning and afternoon to our data. morning is when time <= 57.

We have a dataset: d

```
   box    year   day  time nVisit visit morning
   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>  
 1 212    2020   243    75      0     0 FALSE  
 2 212    2020   243    76      0     0 FALSE  
 3 212    2020   243    77      0     0 FALSE  
 4 212    2020   243    78      0     0 FALSE  
 5 212    2020   243    79      0     0 FALSE  '
```

But what we want is that the visit sum in separate columns grouped by day and box.
So we added this piece:

```r
d3 <- d %>%
  group_by(box, day, morning ) %>%
  summarise_at(vars("visit"), sum)

d3$frac <- d3$visit/57
```

[image: d3 dataframe]

But now we don't know how to make separate column for the counts in the morning and in the afternoon.

If you know maybe how to help up that would be great!

Thanks in advance,
2 starting research students

Comment: What should your output look like? BTW, why do you divide `visit/57`? I thought 57 was a `time` thing.

Comment: we want a tabel with: box- day- visit morning- visit afternoon. That visit/57 we will remove, we wanted to know fractions of the time they are visiting but it did not provided the information we needed so we will remove that indeed because is it is just confusing now.

Comment: I believe the solution here is quite simple, but it's hard to write it without a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It would help if you add a sample to create minimal data frame and the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without data sample I can suggest you the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

d <- d %>%
    mutate(day_part = case_when(
        time <= 57 ~ "morning",
        time > 57 & time <= 114 ~ "afternoon",
        time > 114 ~ "evening"
    )) %>%
    group_by(box, day, day_part) %>%
    summarise(visits = sum(visit, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = day_part, values_from = visits)
```

Comment: Thank you! we can now continue!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_wider

randdat %>%
  mutate(period = if_else(time < 57, "morning", "afternoon")) %>%
  group_by(box, day, period) %>%
  summarize(visit = sum(visit)) %>%
  pivot_wider(box:day, names_from = "period", values_from = "visit") %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#     box   day afternoon morning
#   <dbl> <int>     <int>   <int>
# 1   212   243         2       2
# 2   212   244         3       0
```

---

Data:

```r
set.seed(2021)
randdat <- tibble(
  box = 212,
  year = 2020,
  day = sample(243:244, size = 20, replace = TRUE),
  time = sample(round(runif(20, 0, 100), 0), size = 20),
  visit = sample(0:1, size = 20, replace = TRUE)
) %>% arrange(box, year, day, time)
```